# How to show that the following equation holds?

Tags: random-variables

In Wikipedia appears the pdf's equation for $XY$ and $X/Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are given independent random variables. The equations are

For product $Z=XY$

$$f_Z(z)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\frac{1}{|x|}dx$$

and for the quotient $Z=X/Y$

$$f_Z(z)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|y|f_{XY}(zy,y)dy$$

This equation appears in the following two links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables

Why this two equation holds?

Thanks!

Comment: Please write out the equations in question instead of linking somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know Jacobian and change of variables. I will do the quotient, product is almost identical.

Let us define the following transformation $Z=X/Y$ and $T=Y$. We are going to find joint density $p(Z,T)$ by change of variables from $X,Y$ to $Z,T$. So inverse transformation is,
$$
X=YT\\
Y=T
$$
and Jacobian of this transformation is given by,
$$
J=\begin{vmatrix}
\delta X/\delta Z & \delta X/\delta T \\
\delta T/\delta Z & \delta Y/\delta T
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
T & Z \\
0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=|T|
$$
Then,
$$
p(Z,T)=p(X,Y) J=p(X)p(Y)|T|=p_X(ZT)p_Y(T)|T|
$$
We are looking for $Z$ so we can marginalize out $T$ which gives,
$$
p(Z)=\int p_{X,Y}(ZT,T)|T|dT=\int p_{X,Y}(ZY,Y)|Y|dY
$$

To learn more check [this document](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/n-bivariate.pdf).